# Cannot assign a type to a string in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

hey guys i need help i cannot push a string property to an key,value Array<{name:string}>;
I have

```
         selRoles!: Array<{name:string}>;



  // then i try to map the role.names to the typed Array<{name:string}>.because the map function returns an Array<string> without the type name? 
  this.selRoles = data.roles.map(role => role.name);

  //here is my subscribe method which returns some rest data
  this.userService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data; 
      // i also tried to use forEach with type like this

      data.roles.forEach(role => this.selRoles.push({name:role.name}));
      console.log("selRoles " +this.selRoles.forEach(item => item.name));
}, 
error => console.log(error)
)
```

There is always an error which VC code describes as follows
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'.ts(2345)

How can i assign a type as property of the string? can you help me out. is very appreciated.thanks

Comment: your `.map()` call returns an array of strings, but you need an array of objects that have a property `name`. `data.roles.map(role => {name: role.name});`. alternatively you could change the typehint to Array<string> instead.

Comment: Hi yes i tried that :   this.selRoles = data.roles.map(role => {name:role.name}); But still the compiler says: Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; }[]'.

Comment: eh, yeah I typo'd that. you need a return statement there because otherwise the interpreter thinks that the {} is a function block and not an object. Its correct in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First of all, this.selRoles.forEach return void.Secondly, data.roles.map(role => role.name) I'll return ["string, "string", "string"], you need to change it.

Here is what you need to do:

```js
selRoles!: Array<{name:string}>;

this.selRoles = data.roles.map(role => {return {name: role.name}});

  this.userService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data; 
     

      data.roles.forEach(role => this.selRoles.push({name:role.name}));
      console.log("selRoles " +this.selRoles.map(item => item.name).join(", "));
}, 
error => console.log(error)
)
```

Comment: Yes this was the missing puzzle peace that i needed you recognized it correctly. But i have now another problem when i try to push my selRoles variable which contains the name:strings.     this.user.roles.push(this.selRoles.map(role =>  role.name)); Argument of type '(() => string)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '(() => string)[]' but required in type '{ name: string;

Comment: Try it: this.user.roles.push(...this.selRoles.map(role => {return {name: role.name}}))

Comment: yes the spread operator was the missing peace

Comment: if these things worked for you, can you mark my answer?